# matplotlib assign multiple variables to axes instance with single command

Tags: python, matplotlib

Was there a way to pass a dictionary to an axes method to set instance variables all at once without calling `.set_xlim()`, `.set_ylim()`, and so on individually? I know Matlab has this feature and I thought Matplotlib as well but cannot find the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`plt.setp`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp)  (Also see `getp`).

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

linestyle = dict(color='red', marker='^', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(range(10))

plt.setp(ax, xlim=[-1, 12], ylim=[-5, 12], xlabel='X-axis')
plt.setp(line, **linestyle)

plt.show()
```

[image]

`setp` and `getp` are "matlab-isms", so a lot of people feel that they are "unpythonic" and shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary.

Obviously, you can do all of this in other ways (e.g. setting the axis limits with `ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])` or just expanding the `linestyle` dict when calling `plot`).

`setp` is still very useful, though.  It automatically operates on sequences of artists, so you can do things like `plt.setp([ax1, ax2, ax3], **parameters)`.  This is especially handy for things like ticks and ticklabels, where you're often operating of a bunch of artists at once.

It also allows for easy introspection of matplotlib artists.  Try calling things like `plt.setp(ax)` to see a list of all parameters or `plt.setp(line, 'marker')` to see a list of all valid arguments to `line.set_marker`.

Comment: Thanks! How is that unpythonic though? It's so awesome.

Comment: I can't imagine why the verbose `set_` methods confer any practical or aesthetic advantage.

Comment: I agree. `setp` and `getp` are quite handy.  The setters and getters are partly there because they pre-date python having properties, but in this case, they're what allow `setp` to work without a lot of "magical" code. It just looks for methods that start with "set" (of course, you could still do this with properties).  Either way, I completely agree that the setters and getters are some of matplotlib's bigger warts.

Comment: On another side note, all matplotlib artists have a `artist.set` and `artist.get` method that allows for most of the same functionality.